# How to access a method in an object within another object, from the outside?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am in ViewController, trying to access a method in object "cat" owned by object "backgroundpicture". ViewController has an instance of backgroundpicture.

The method/message in "cat.h":

```
@interface Cat : NSObject
    -(BOOL)checkIfTouchHit:(float) xx :(float) yy; 
@end
```

"Cat.m":

```
- (BOOL)checkIfTouchHit:(float) xx :(float) yy{
    NSLog(@"Inside checkIfTouchHit");
    return YES;
}
```

"BackGroundPicture.h":

```
#import "Cat.h"

@interface BackGroundPicture : NSObject
    @property (strong) Cat * katt;
@end
```

"BackGroundPicture.m":

```
@implementation BackGroundPicture
    @synthesize katt = _katt
@end
```

"ViewController.m":

```
@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong) BackGroundPicture * bakgrunnsbilde;
@end

@implementation BackGroundPicture
@synthesize bakgrunnsbilde = _bakgrunnsbilde;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{...
[[self.bakgrunnsbilde katt] checkIfTouchHit :(float)touchLocation.x :(float)touchLocation.y]   
...}
```

The string inside the method "checkIfInside" in cat will not show up. I also tried
    [_bakgrunnsbilde katt]...
but with the same lack of result, and I believe this is compiled the same way. I am wondering what I am missing here, and hope someone can help. Thanks :)

*edit* I forgot to add a few lines from my BackGroundPicture.m. It is a method run on start from the ViewDidLoad in ViewController. It is like this in BackGroundPicture.m:

```
- (void)createObjects {    
Cat * katt = [[Cat alloc] init];
}
```

it is called from ViewController.m like so:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[_bakgrunnsbilde createObjects];
}
```

I know that this get executed. I hope this edit makes sense, my head is ruined after a long day :) Going to check back tomorrow morning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will work, but BackGroundPicture.m needs to allocate a cat first.

So in BackGroundPicture.m, do this:

```
- (id)init {

    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _katt = [[Cat alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}
```

In general, remember to allocate objects before you use them.  You may also need to create a BackGroundPicture, too as Valentin points out.  In viewDidLoad, do this:

```
bakgrunnsbilde = [[BackGroundPicture alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer! I couldn't upvote though. I am really sorry I forgot to include this code here (not in my BackGroundPicture.m though)

      Cat * katt = [[AAAPictureObject alloc] init];

(I couldn't format this message like my original post)

Comment: yeah, mb as you can see from my edit this was my problem! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're accessing the method correctly. You could use the property, for readability sake (you also don't need the cast)

`[self.bakgrunnsbilde.katt checkIfTouchHit:touchLocation.x :touchLocation.y]`

, but your way of doing it should work as well.

You should check if your `-viewDidLoad` method gets called and if `self.bakgrunnsbilde` or `self.bakgrunnsbilde.katt` is not `nil` when `-viewDidLoad` gets called. One of this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you as well! I will check back tomorrow :)